# What is the options parameter in a Handlebars helper function?

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

I am creating a custom handlebar helper but it always throws `Object #<Object> has no method 'fn'` when compiled through the terminal.

My handlebar helper is:

```
module.exports.register = function (Handlebars, opts, params)  { 
    Handlebars.registerHelper('compimg', function (context, opts)  { 
        var compImg = ["assets/img/icon-nope.png","assets/img/icon-check.png"];
        return compImg[opts.fn(context)];
    });
}
```

My .hbs file is:

```
{{#each checkable}}
   <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 icon-container"><img src="{{compimg this}}"></div>
{{/each}}
```

My JSON file is:

```
{
    "desc": "blablabla",
    "checkable": [
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1
    ]
}
```

When I checked the official documentation I found this piece of code. Can someone explain what exactly `context` and `options` are here?

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('each', function(context, options) {
  var ret = "";

  for(var i=0, j=context.length; i<j; i++) {
    ret = ret + options.fn(context[i]);
  }

  return ret;
});
```

Answer (score 10):

The handlebars example for `each` is a block helper, which means that there is more markup or template syntax between the `{{#each}}` and `{{/each}}` tags. When you use this syntax, Handlebars passes an `options` parameter to your helper as the last argument. The `options` object contains a `fn` method that works just like a compiled template... `var html = options.fn(context);` gives you the rendered template from inside the block.

The `context` variable is the thing that you're passing into your helper and can be any number of arguments if you want more.

Since you're making an inline helper and a not a block helper, I think you only need to change one line...

```
return compImg[opts.fn(context)];
```

to

```
return compImg[context];
```